# Find out who changed the date on linux?

Tags: linux, date

I'm currently trying to change the date on my Linux machine: `date +%s -s @1637142120`

Somehow, the date gets resented after some seconds. Is there any way to find out which program / system is responsible for this?

Comment: I think ```chronyd``` or similar service is running on your system which is undoing your changes. Can you share the output of ```systemctl status chronyd``` ?

Comment: There could be any number of services which deal with setting the system time. The typical ones are related to NTP. The details of how time is sync'd from some NTP server depend on which "Linux" OS you are running. In addition to `chronyd` like mentioned above, it could be `systemd-timesyncd`. If this Linux machine is running in a VM, then it could be the host OS.